# A differential equation and a Jacobi field

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I have a question about the following answer here: [Zero Sectional Curvature implies exp is a local isometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1173648/zero-sectional-curvature-implies-exp-is-a-local-isometry)

We have $w\in T_v(T_pM)\cong T_pM$, the geodesics $\gamma_s(t)=\exp_p(t(v+sw))$ and the Jacobi field along $\gamma_0$, $J(t)=(d\exp_p)(tw)$.

If we suppose the sectional curvature is zero then $\dfrac{\partial^2 J}{\partial t^2}=0$.

Let $\{e_i\}$ be an orthonormal basis of $T_pM$ and take the parallel transport along $\gamma_0$, $e_i(t)$ such that $e_i(0)=e_ i$. Then we can write $J(t)=a^i(t)e_i(t)$ and $w=w^ie_i$.

(This is the part I don't understand:) Solving the above equation we have $J(t)=(w^it)e_i(t)$.

How do yo conclude that? Can anyone explain?

Thank you very much.

Comment: It's just solving an ordinary differential equation for $a^i$. Show $J(0)=0$ and $J'(0) = W$ (where the prime denotes covariant differentiation wrt. $t$ along $\gamma_0$). Now $e_i(t)$ beeing parallel we have $J''(t)=0 = {a^i}''(t)e_i(t)$ and thus $a^i(t) = c_1 t + c_2$. From the initial conditions we then get $a^i = w^i t$.

Comment: Did you mean $J'(0)=w$? Thank you @hase_olaf

Comment: Yes of course, in my personal notation vectors always have capital letters, sorry for not adapting to your notation...